# word2vec installation Failed building wheel Could not build wheels for word2vec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: pip, word2vec, pypi, python-packaging, pep517

I'm trying to *pip*-install [*`word2vec`*](https://pypi.org/project/word2vec/) and I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for word2vec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for word2vec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show more details about your environment, for example the output of `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip debug --verbose` would be quite helpful to help you.